# Identifying continuous and categorical data using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
DATA = data.table(col1 = rbinom(10,10,.5),
                  col2 = rnorm(10),
                  col3 = rbinom(10,1,.5),
                  col4 = rbinom(10,10,.5),
                  col5 = rbinom(10,1,.5))
```

I have a large data set where continuous variables are either of class `integer` or `numeric` and categorical variables are of class `integer`. Hence I am looking for other rule that would allow me to distinguish between continuous and categorical variables. All of the categorical variables are `0-1` as presented in the table.

As the data set is large I would prefer to use the `data.table` package.

Comment: What is your expected otuput meant for? Just for a human to explore the data further or for automatic processing which requires to have the exact names of the categorical variables?

Comment: It is aimed for automatic processing.

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question then (e. g. do you want to have two vectors with column names) to help us giving a precise answer. THX :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
apply(DATA, 2, function(x) ifelse(all(x %in% 0:1), 1, 0))
```

Or:

```
apply(DATA, 2, function(x) all(x %in% 0:1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a more generic solution:

Why? What shall happen if you have dirty data in the categorical columns (e. g. a value > 1)?

If your dataset is big enough you could try to tabulate (`table`) each column and count the distinct values. A low number of distinct values is a good indicator for a categorical variable:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

size = 1000

data = data.table(
  col1 = rbinom(size, 10, .5),
  col2 = rnorm(size),
  col3 = rbinom(size, 1, .5),
  col4 = rbinom(size, 10, .5),
  col5 = rbinom(size, 1, .5)
)

lapply(data, function(x) length(table(x)))
# $col1
# [1] 11
# 
# $col2
# [1] 1000
# 
# $col3
# [1] 2
# 
# $col4
# [1] 11
# 
# $col5
# [1] 2
```

Here col2 is most likely continuous all the other columns seem to be categorical.

You could use an absolute (max. number of different values) or relative (number of different values divided by the number of observations/rows) value to split the result into continuous and categorical...

If also want to know the min and max values per column you could use:

```
lapply(data, function(x) c(distincts = length(table(x)), min = min(x), msx = max(x) ))
```

to get

```
$col1
distincts       min       msx 
       11         0        10 

$col2
  distincts         min         msx 
1000.000000   -2.809775    3.390371 

$col3
distincts       min       msx 
        2         0         1 

$col4
distincts       min       msx 
       11         0        10 

$col5
distincts       min       msx 
        2         0         1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion and indeed obtaining a more general solution would come in handy. However this approach fails in my case as for instance I have a variable informing about the number of cell phones and the total number of distinct values is 5 which is less than the number of levels for some categorical variables.